# How to export only selected resources from OSB (Eclipse workspace) into sbconfig.jar using Ant?

Tags: eclipse, oracle, ant, osb

I am trying to build an Oracle Service Bus proxy deployment archives for OSB PS5 (so I can't use configjar).
Proxies have been built with Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse.

In order to get small archives for each proxy, I want to build different archives with selected resources (Business services, Transformations, etc.) according to each proxy.

Using OEPE, this is done by exporting OSB archive at resource level. I select only needed proxy, tick 'Include dependencies', and that's all. Resulting sbconfig.jar has <imp:property name="projectLevelExport" value="false"/> in 'ExportInfo' and resources only for the proxy selected.

All the examples for exporting with Ant use Eclipse 'com.bea.alsb.core.ConfigExport' application in such way:

```
  <java dir="${osb.home}/lib" classpathref="library.osb"
        jar="${eclipse.home}/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar"
        fork="true" failonerror="true" maxmemory="768m">
     <jvmarg line="-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"/>   
     <arg line="-data ${workspace.dir}"/>
     <arg line="-application com.bea.alsb.core.ConfigExport"/>
     <arg line="-configProject ${config.project}"/>
     <arg line="-configJar ${config.jar}"/>
     <arg line="-exportLevel false"/>
     <arg line="-configSubProjects ${config.subprojects}"/>
     <arg line="-includeDependencies ${config.includeDependencies}"/>
     <sysproperty key="weblogic.home" value="${weblogic.home}"/>
     <sysproperty key="osb.home" value="${osb.home}"/>
     <sysproperty key="harvester.home" value="${osb.home}/harvester"/>
     <sysproperty key="sun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax" value="true"/>
     <sysproperty key="osgi.bundlefile.limit" value="750"/>
     <sysproperty key="middleware.home" value="${fmw.home}"/>
  </java>
```

So it exports resources in Eclipse workspace at project level, including all the proxies and so on.
So is there any way to export proxy with selected resources?

Comment: I would rethink organisation of projects. In my opinion you want to operate on project level for build&deploy. Split something up, have resource only projects, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem is solved in unusual way. I used configjar.jar from OSB PS6 (simply copied into custom folder) with the other libraries from OSB PS5. Also I used

```
<java fork="true" classname="com.bea.alsb.tools.configjar.ConfigJar" ...>
```

instead of configJar task.

Comment: Can you please provide us the final ant file in order to understand the changes? And how you could export specific files from Project? (ex. Only Proxy and XSDs)